# How do I figure out which account I've used to log in?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

This is my user account:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/523350/smacdonald

Is there a way to figure out which email address or account is associated with that user so that I can log in to it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

Comment: I can't log in to the original account, so I'll fill out the form. Thanks!

Comment: Please Read the last line of that link page.

Comment: The instructions say that I need to edit the About Me section of each account. But if I can't access the original 'smacdonald' account, how do I edit its About Me section?

Comment: Have a look at to the last line "If you have lost access to your duplicate account, please click here to fill out the form." and if that doesnt work then best option is to [contact directly](http://stackoverflow.com/help/other)

Comment: All sorted! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've marked this as CW because I don't want to steal rep from Lucifer.

You'll need to go to stackoverflow.com/help/user-merge

The instructions there say that you'll need to edit the About Me section of each account to merge. If you don't have access to the account, you can fill out the linked form.

If that doesn't work, your best option is always to just contact SE directly.